# Custom JS minify on the fly

Tags: regex, minify, regex-negation

I am having trouble with my regex to remove comments from JavaScript.
I have two regexes.  The first is to remove `/* */` comments: `!/\*[^*]*\*+([^/][^*]*\*+)*/!` which works perfectly. The second is to remove `//` comments: `^(?!:)\/\/.*`

I added `^(?!:)\/\/.*` to avoid remove url from JS but it doesn't work.

You can test here  : https://regex101.com/r/vP4gL5/1

```
//Init Layout

// Cookie law
url : 'http://fakeurl.com/cookielaw',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add multiline modifier and `.*` inside the negative lookahead. `^(?!:)` this checks for the not of `:` only at the start. So this  matches the strings which has `:` at the middle or at the last.

```
'~^(?!.*:)\/\/.*~m'
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vP4gL5/2)

Seems like `^\/\/.*` also works. It matches all the lines which starts with `//`. And it's better to add a pattern to match the leading spaces also like

```
^\h*\/\/.*
```

think `<space>//foo` also consider as a comment line.